# web worker postMessage process order

Tags: javascript, web-worker

With the following code:

HTML FILE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>
        <title></title>
        <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="worker.js"></script>-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="run.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id='log'></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

run.js:

```
window.onload = function(){

    var worker = new Worker('worker.js');

    var log = document.getElementById('log');

    log.innerHTML += "<p>"+"test"+"</p>";

    worker.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
        //alert(e.data);
        log.innerHTML += '<p>' + e.data + '</p>';
    }, false);

    for(var i=1; i<21;i++){
        worker.postMessage(i);
    }
};
```

worker.js

```
self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
  self.postMessage(e.data);
}, false);
```

the output is as I would expect a list of 1 to 20, but if I uncomment the alert call in the run.js message listener it prints out 20 to 1 instead. Is this because of the alert causing the delay in writing to the page and the message processing is backed up in a stack so the last one on is the first one off? or is it something else.

Comment: Fun fact: In Firefox I see 20, 19, 18, ... as described by you. In Chrome it is 1, 2, 3, ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes this is because of "alert()". It blocks the further execution of the code inside the block of the worker listener. By other words, the code:

```
log.innerHTML += '<p>' + e.data + '</p>';
```

is executed only after the "OK" button on the modal window of the alert box is pressed, in wich order you will press them, in this order the "log.innerHTML" will be changed, so you press them in descending order and that's why you get this result. If you don't use alert messages everything goes well.

Comment: This does not seem to be the correct answer. Why does alert show data in reverse (20 to 1)? And this happens in firefox only. Seems to be something like firefox suddenly starts using stack when alert is present. Not clear what's going on from this answer.

Comment: @tapananand this is the correct answer, as I wrote, in which order the alerts are pressed in that order the messages are written to the log, in this case the browser is opening 20 modal dialogs (alerts), one over another, firefox is showing them differently than chrome, unfortunately we can not move the modal dialogs, but if we could we could achieve any arbitrary order like: 2, 1, 15, 3, 20, 5 ...

Comment: As far as I know, alert stops execution of any JS code in the same thread, so at a time only one alert can exist. So, it's not possible that all alerts are shown at once. Unless alert doesn't block execution, which I doubt.

Comment: please inform yourself about alerts and that JavaScript is not multithreaded, in this case every modal dialog is opened asynchronously, in different ticks of the main loop, that's why multiple alerts are possible in this case

Comment: By threads I meant - workers (Javascript is no longer singlethreaded thanks to workers). If I debug the code, why doesn't the next breakpoint hit until I press OK? If multiple alerts could be opened the break point would have hit independent of me clicking OK

Comment: just put before the alert modal dialog a `console.log()` with the `e.data` argument, see the browser console and answer your questions yourself

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116659/discussion-between-tapananand-and-micnic).

Answer (score 0):

I think this was a bug in Firefox. I'm not seeing this behavior in 2020 in any browser I tried: they all order from 1 to 20.